# I can't position a SVG where I need to. Using Tailwind

Tags: laravel, svg, vuejs3, tailwind-css, dropzone.js

I am struggling with the positioning of an SVG.
Previously it was located correctly.
Now it's scrolled up and I can't figure out how to get it back into place.

I'm using Laravel 9, Vue 3 as SFC, dropzone.js, and tailwind.

This is the SVG file:

```
<svg style="display:block" viewBox="0 0 143 71" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <title>Group 6</title>
    <g id="4---Emi-/-Inspección" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="Desk_EMI/Inspección/Online-Copy-4" transform="translate(-624.000000, -360.000000)">
            <g id="Group-5" transform="translate(573.500000, 302.870620)">
                <g id="Group-6" transform="translate(51.000000, 58.000000)">
                    <rect id="Rectangle-Copy" x="0" y="0" width="142" height="70"></rect>
                    <g id="Group-98-Copy" opacity="0.6" transform="translate(22.199480, 2.602315)">
                        <polygon id="Fill-4" fill="#222222" points="13.5269156 65.7173338 15.1988749 65.7173338 15.1988749 61.6858467 13.5269156 61.6858467"></polygon>
                        <polygon id="Fill-5" fill="#222222" points="11.2589031 65.7173338 12.9308624 65.7173338 12.9308624 61.6858467 11.2589031 61.6858467"></polygon>
                        <g id="Group-97">
                            <path d="M15.7948077,65.7170929 L16.3192141,65.7170929 C17.4932583,65.7170929 18.4445351,64.765214 18.4445351,63.5917719 L18.4445351,61.6856058 L15.7948077,61.6856058 L15.7948077,65.7170929 Z" id="Fill-6" fill="#222222"></path>
                            <path d="M6.67724081,61.6854252 C6.35452918,61.6854252 6.04265488,61.6390655 5.74462828,61.5601938 L5.74462828,63.5915913 C5.74462828,64.7650334 6.69650718,65.7169123 7.87055136,65.7169123 L8.39555983,65.7169123 L8.39555983,61.6854252 L6.67724081,61.6854252 Z" id="Fill-8" fill="#222222"></path>
                            <polygon id="Fill-10" fill="#222222" points="8.99089055 65.7173338 10.6628499 65.7173338 10.6628499 61.6858467 8.99089055 61.6858467"></polygon>
                            <polygon id="Fill-12" fill="#171717" points="8.39543942 65.7173338 8.99089055 65.7173338 8.99089055 61.6858467 8.39543942 61.6858467"></polygon>
                           
                            <path d="M8.3952588,61.6854252 L8.3952588,59.6684775 C7.34584392,59.6630589 6.40359821,59.2090951 5.74492932,58.4908209 L5.74492932,61.5601938 C6.04295592,61.6390655 6.35422814,61.6854252 6.67693978,61.6854252 L8.3952588,61.6854252 Z" id="Fill-20" fill="#222222"></path>
                            <path d="M8.3952588,61.6854252 L8.3952588,59.6684775 C7.34584392,59.6630589 6.40359821,59.2090951 5.74492932,58.4908209 L5.74492932,61.5601938 C6.04295592,61.6390655 6.35422814,61.6854252 6.67693978,61.6854252 L8.3952588,61.6854252 Z" id="Fill-21" fill="#171717"></path>
                            <polygon id="Fill-22" fill="#222222" points="11.2589031 61.6858467 12.9308624 61.6858467 12.9308624 59.669501 11.2589031 59.669501"></polygon>
                            <polygon id="Fill-23" fill="#171717" points="11.2589031 61.6858467 12.9308624 61.6858467 12.9308624 59.669501 11.2589031 59.669501"></polygon>
                            <polygon id="Fill-24" fill="#222222" points="15.7949281 61.6852446 18.4446555 61.6852446 18.4446555 59.668899 15.7949281 59.668899"></polygon>
                            <polygon id="Fill-25" fill="#171717" points="15.7949281 61.6852446 18.4446555 61.6852446 18.4446555 59.668899 15.7949281 59.668899"></polygon>
                            <path d="M8.99089055,61.6854252 L8.99089055,59.6690796 L8.41590993,59.6690796 C8.40868505,59.6690796 8.40206223,59.6684775 8.39543942,59.6684775 L8.39543942,61.6854252 L8.99089055,61.6854252 Z" id="Fill-26" fill="#171717"></path>
                            <path d="M8.99089055,61.6854252 L8.99089055,59.6690796 L8.41590993,59.6690796 C8.40868505,59.6690796 8.40206223,59.6684775 8.39543942,59.6684775 L8.39543942,61.6854252 L8.99089055,61.6854252 Z" id="Fill-27" fill="#171717"></path>
                            <polygon id="Fill-28" fill="#171717" points="10.6634519 61.6858467 11.2589031 61.6858467 11.2589031 59.669501 10.6634519 59.669501"></polygon>
                            <polygon id="Fill-29" fill="#171717" points="10.6634519 61.6858467 11.2589031 61.6858467 11.2589031 59.669501 10.6634519 59.669501"></polygon>
                            <polygon id="Fill-30" fill="#171717" points="12.9308624 61.6858467 13.5269156 61.6858467 13.5269156 59.669501 12.9308624 59.669501"></polygon>
                            <polygon id="Fill-31" fill="#171717" points="12.9308624 61.6858467 13.5269156 61.6858467 13.5269156 59.669501 12.9308624 59.669501"></polygon>
                            <polygon id="Fill-32" fill="#171717" points="15.199477 61.6858467 15.7949281 61.6858467 15.7949281 59.669501 15.199477 59.669501"></polygon>
                            <polygon id="Fill-33" fill="#171717" points="15.199477 61.6858467 15.7949281 61.6858467 15.7949281 59.669501 15.199477 59.669501"></polygon>
                            <path d="M13.9397577,20.0388871 L9.12135997,20.0388871 L9.12135997,23.132343 C9.78243715,23.132343 10.4176252,23.3448751 10.9558793,23.718763 L12.6489112,22.9806204 L13.9397577,20.0388871 Z" id="Fill-34" fill="#4EA19B"></path>
                            <path d="M9.12142018,19.8348443 C9.12142018,18.5385791 8.07080115,17.48796 6.77453596,17.48796 L2.64551289,17.48796 C1.18427944,17.48796 0,18.6716374 0,20.1334729 L0,21.2418911 C0,22.7037266 1.18427944,23.8874039 2.64551289,23.8874039 L8.43264759,23.8874039 C8.81315832,23.8874039 9.12142018,23.5797442 9.12142018,23.1992334 L9.12142018,23.1324032 L9.12142018,20.0389473 L9.12142018,19.8348443 Z" id="Fill-35" fill="#7EC7C0"></path>
                            <path d="M24.4172892,9.2103465 C25.3998739,5.84595733 26.858699,4.71165002 31.4151946,4.71165002 L48.7338515,4.71165002 L66.0513042,4.71165002 C70.6084018,4.71165002 72.067227,5.84595733 73.0498116,9.2103465 L76.60265,21.8719614 L82.3500478,21.8719614 L76.5659234,8.68413387 C74.7350166,4.51055733 70.6084018,1.81447023 66.0513042,1.81447023 L48.7338515,1.81447023 L31.4151946,1.81447023 C26.858699,1.81447023 22.7314822,4.51055733 20.9005753,8.68413387 L15.1170531,21.8719614 L20.8644509,21.8719614 L24.4172892,9.2103465 Z" id="Fill-36" fill="#4EA19B"></path>
                            <polygon id="Fill-37" fill="#CCE7E4" points="27.5799234 20.8893166 31.6860677 20.8893166 31.6860677 19.1884577 27.5799234 19.1884577"></polygon>
                            <path d="M25.5696587,34.5597666 L25.5702608,34.5597666 C24.6533022,33.1400762 22.9024712,29.4644148 20.6627561,26.811075 C20.6573375,26.8044522 20.6519188,26.7984314 20.6465001,26.7924107 C20.0793465,26.1217003 20.5375248,25.0969705 21.4153486,25.0969705 L21.9216927,25.0969705 L48.7338515,25.0969705 L75.544806,25.0969705 L76.0517523,25.0969705 C76.9301782,25.0969705 77.3871523,26.1217003 76.8199986,26.7924107 C76.81458,26.7984314 76.8091613,26.8044522 76.8043447,26.811075 C74.5640276,29.4644148 72.8144007,33.1400762 71.89684,34.5597666 C73.8559886,31.525916 76.8187945,29.2175645 80.3427333,28.1524957 C81.1741974,27.9008288 81.6931851,27.8189468 81.6931851,27.8189468 L82.3500478,21.8722625 L76.60265,21.8722625 L74.8861372,21.8722625 L60.7807489,21.8722625 L48.7338515,21.8722625 L36.6857499,21.8722625 L22.5803616,21.8722625 L20.8644509,21.8722625 L15.1170531,21.8722625 L15.7733137,27.8189468 C15.7733137,27.8189468 16.2923014,27.9008288 17.1249697,28.1524957 C20.6477043,29.2175645 23.6105101,31.525916 25.5696587,34.5597666" id="Fill-38" fill="#A9D8D3"></path>
                            <path d="M24.4419742,51.5219355 L24.4419742,45.3573004 L24.4419742,51.5219355 C24.4419742,53.8507575 26.3300781,55.7388613 28.6589001,55.7388613 C26.3300781,55.7388613 24.4419742,53.8507575 24.4419742,51.5219355" id="Fill-39" fill="#4EA19B"></path>
                            <path d="M47.3578115,7.32007516 L48.7335504,7.32007516 L50.1086873,7.32007516 C50.6084087,7.32007516 51.0136044,6.9148794 51.0136044,6.41515803 L51.0136044,6.14843927 L51.0136044,5.88111844 C51.0136044,5.38139707 50.6084087,4.97620131 50.1086873,4.97620131 L48.7335504,4.97620131 L47.3578115,4.97620131 C46.8580901,4.97620131 46.4528943,5.38139707 46.4528943,5.88111844 L46.4528943,6.14843927 L46.4528943,6.41515803 C46.4528943,6.9148794 46.8580901,7.32007516 47.3578115,7.32007516" id="Fill-40" fill="#86CAC4"></path>
                            <path d="M27.5799234,20.8887145 L31.6860677,20.8887145 L31.6860677,19.1878556 L27.5799234,19.1878556 L27.5799234,20.8887145 Z M35.7025029,20.8893166 L32.8956342,20.8893166 L32.8956342,19.1878556 L33.6530432,19.1878556 C34.3345909,19.1878556 34.8577932,18.5845775 34.7614614,17.9108568 L34.0359623,12.8353735 C33.863167,11.6227966 32.8239874,10.7220939 31.598767,10.7220939 L27.6672241,10.7220939 C26.4420037,10.7220939 25.4034261,11.6227966 25.2300288,12.8353735 L24.5051318,17.9108568 C24.4081979,18.5845775 24.9320022,19.1878556 25.6129479,19.1878556 L26.3703569,19.1878556 L26.3703569,20.8893166 L23.5634882,20.8893166 C23.0204175,20.8893166 22.5803014,21.3294326 22.5803014,21.8719012 L36.6856897,21.8719012 C36.6856897,21.3294326 36.2455736,20.8893166 35.7025029,20.8893166 L35.7025029,20.8893166 Z" id="Fill-41" fill="#86CAC4"></path>
                            <path d="M11.3392197,37.5119759 C11.3392197,34.7942142 12.270026,32.1583345 13.9775077,30.0444529 L15.7734943,27.8185855 C15.7734943,27.8185855 11.3891919,31.1956182 10.1796253,33.3624824 C8.97005879,35.5293465 8.8472357,37.9779812 9.12117935,38.3518691 L11.4548179,37.8611788 C11.3867836,37.7594283 11.3392197,37.6432281 11.3392197,37.5119759" id="Fill-42" fill="#7EC7C0"></path>
                            <path d="M11.4550588,37.8611788 L9.12142018,38.351267 C9.67593027,39.1074719 24.8451832,39.8636767 27.7688542,39.5108614 L11.9240744,38.1495722 C11.7235837,38.1327142 11.5598196,38.0183201 11.4550588,37.8611788" id="Fill-43" fill="#5ABCB5"></path>
                            <path d="M25.5702608,34.5597666 L25.5696587,34.5597666 C26.2506044,35.6139981 26.8123393,36.7543261 27.2307807,37.9614843 L27.7684328,39.5112227 L39.1717132,39.5816653 C40.9394023,39.5925026 42.5312857,38.5129841 43.1743007,36.8669139 L44.0713909,34.5724101 L25.5702608,34.5597666 Z" id="Fill-44" fill="#5ABCB5"></path>
                            <path d="M22.8544859,38.0999011 C21.9778662,38.0999011 21.2668169,37.3888518 21.2668169,36.5122322 C21.2668169,35.6356125 21.9778662,34.9251653 22.8544859,34.9251653 C23.7317076,34.9251653 24.4421549,35.6356125 24.4421549,36.5122322 C24.4421549,37.3888518 23.7317076,38.0999011 22.8544859,38.0999011 M17.3485197,36.6073598 C15.6440484,36.6073598 14.2622887,35.2249981 14.2622887,33.5205268 C14.2622887,31.8154534 15.6440484,30.4336937 17.3485197,30.4336937 C19.0541952,30.4336937 20.4353528,31.8154534 20.4353528,33.5205268 C20.4353528,35.2249981 19.0541952,36.6073598 17.3485197,36.6073598 M25.5698394,34.5597064 C23.6106908,31.5258558 20.6478849,29.2175043 17.1245482,28.1530376 C16.292482,27.9013707 15.7734943,27.8188866 15.7734943,27.8188866 L13.9775077,30.0441518 C12.270026,32.1586355 11.3392197,34.7945152 11.3392197,37.5116749 C11.3392197,37.642927 11.3867836,37.7597294 11.4548179,37.8614799 C11.5595788,38.0180191 11.723945,38.1330152 11.9244356,38.1498733 L27.7686134,39.5111625 L27.2309614,37.9620262 C26.8119179,36.7542659 26.250785,35.6139378 25.5698394,34.5597064" id="Fill-45" fill="#F8F4B5"></path>
                            <path d="M17.3487606,35.3976127 C16.3131934,35.3976127 15.471494,34.5559133 15.471494,33.5203461 C15.471494,32.484779 16.3131934,31.6430796 17.3487606,31.6430796 C18.3843277,31.6430796 19.2260271,32.484779 19.2260271,33.5203461 C19.2260271,34.5559133 18.3843277,35.3976127 17.3487606,35.3976127 M17.3487606,30.4335131 C15.6442892,30.4335131 14.2619275,31.8152727 14.2619275,33.5203461 C14.2619275,35.2248175 15.6442892,36.6071792 17.3487606,36.6071792 C19.0538339,36.6071792 20.4355936,35.2248175 20.4355936,33.5203461 C20.4355936,31.8152727 19.0538339,30.4335131 17.3487606,30.4335131" id="Fill-46" fill="#F2F8F8"></path>
                            <path d="M17.3487606,31.642899 C16.3131934,31.642899 15.471494,32.4845983 15.471494,33.5201655 C15.471494,34.5557327 16.3131934,35.3974321 17.3487606,35.3974321 C18.3843277,35.3974321 19.2260271,34.5557327 19.2260271,33.5201655 C19.2260271,32.4845983 18.3843277,31.642899 17.3487606,31.642899" id="Fill-47" fill="#FFFFFF"></path>
                            <path d="M22.8550278,36.8898529 C22.6461081,36.8898529 22.4769253,36.7206702 22.4769253,36.5117505 C22.4769253,36.3034329 22.6461081,36.1342501 22.8550278,36.1342501 C23.0633453,36.1342501 23.2331302,36.3034329 23.2331302,36.5117505 C23.2331302,36.7206702 23.0633453,36.8898529 22.8550278,36.8898529 M22.8544257,34.9246836 C21.977806,34.9246836 21.2667567,35.6357329 21.2667567,36.5123526 C21.2667567,37.3889722 21.977806,38.1000216 22.8544257,38.1000216 C23.7316474,38.1000216 24.4420947,37.3889722 24.4420947,36.5123526 C24.4420947,35.6357329 23.7316474,34.9246836 22.8544257,34.9246836" id="Fill-48" fill="#F2F8F8"></path>
                            <path d="M22.8550278,36.1343706 C22.6461081,36.1343706 22.4769253,36.3035533 22.4769253,36.5118709 C22.4769253,36.7207906 22.6461081,36.8899734 22.8550278,36.8899734 C23.0633453,36.8899734 23.2331302,36.7207906 23.2331302,36.5118709 C23.2331302,36.3035533 23.0633453,36.1343706 22.8550278,36.1343706" id="Fill-49" fill="#FFFFFF"></path>
                            <polygon id="Fill-50" fill="#222222" points="86.8035285 65.7173338 88.4754878 65.7173338 88.4754878 61.6858467 86.8035285 61.6858467"></polygon>
                            <polygon id="Fill-51" fill="#222222" points="82.2675034 65.7173338 83.9400648 65.7173338 83.9400648 61.6858467 82.2675034 61.6858467"></polygon>
                            <path d="M79.0219637,61.6854252 L79.0219637,63.5915913 C79.0219637,64.7650334 79.9732405,65.7169123 81.1472847,65.7169123 L81.6716911,65.7169123 L81.6716911,61.6854252 L79.0219637,61.6854252 Z" id="Fill-52" fill="#222222"></path>
                            <path d="M89.0714206,61.6854252 L89.0714206,65.7169123 L89.595827,65.7169123 C90.7698712,65.7169123 91.7217501,64.7650334 91.7217501,63.5915913 L91.7217501,61.5601938 C91.4237235,61.6390655 91.1124513,61.6854252 90.7897396,61.6854252 L89.0714206,61.6854252 Z" id="Fill-53" fill="#222222"></path>
                            <polygon id="Fill-54" fill="#222222" points="84.536118 65.7173338 86.2080774 65.7173338 86.2080774 61.6858467 84.536118 61.6858467"></polygon>
                            <polygon id="Fill-55" fill="#171717" points="88.4760899 65.7173338 89.071541 65.7173338 89.071541 61.6858467 88.4760899 61.6858467"></polygon>
                            <polygon id="Fill-56" fill="#171717" points="86.2080774 65.7173338 86.8035285 65.7173338 86.8035285 61.6858467 86.2080774 61.6858467"></polygon>
                            <polygon id="Fill-57" fill="#171717" points="83.9400648 65.7173338 84.535516 65.7173338 84.535516 61.6858467 83.9400648 61.6858467"></polygon>
                            <polygon id="Fill-58" fill="#171717" points="81.6720523 65.7173338 82.2675034 65.7173338 82.2675034 61.6858467 81.6720523 61.6858467"></polygon>
                            <polygon id="Fill-59" fill="#222222" points="82.2675034 61.6858467 83.9400648 61.6858467 83.9400648 59.669501 82.2675034 59.669501"></polygon>
                            <polygon id="Fill-60" fill="#171717" points="82.2675034 61.6858467 83.9400648 61.6858467 83.9400648 59.669501 82.2675034 59.669501"></polygon>
                            <polygon id="Fill-61" fill="#222222" points="84.536118 61.6858467 86.2080774 61.6858467 86.2080774 59.669501 84.536118 59.669501"></polygon>
                            <polygon id="Fill-62" fill="#171717" points="84.536118 61.6858467 86.2080774 61.6858467 86.2080774 59.669501 84.536118 59.669501"></polygon>
                            <polygon id="Fill-63" fill="#222222" points="86.8041306 61.6858467 88.4760899 61.6858467 88.4760899 59.669501 86.8041306 59.669501"></polygon>
                            <polygon id="Fill-64" fill="#171717" points="86.8041306 61.6858467 88.4760899 61.6858467 88.4760899 59.669501 86.8041306 59.669501"></polygon>
                            <path d="M89.0714206,59.6687183 L89.0714206,61.685666 L90.7897396,61.685666 C91.1124513,61.685666 91.4237235,61.6387043 91.7217501,61.5604347 L91.7217501,58.4910617 C91.0630812,59.2087339 90.1214376,59.6626976 89.0714206,59.6687183" id="Fill-65" fill="#222222"></path>
                            <path d="M89.0714206,59.6687183 L89.0714206,61.685666 L90.7897396,61.685666 C91.1124513,61.685666 91.4237235,61.6387043 91.7217501,61.5604347 L91.7217501,58.4910617 C91.0630812,59.2087339 90.1214376,59.6626976 89.0714206,59.6687183" id="Fill-66" fill="#171717"></path>
                            <polygon id="Fill-67" fill="#222222" points="79.0223249 61.6858467 81.6720523 61.6858467 81.6720523 59.669501 79.0223249 59.669501"></polygon>
                            <polygon id="Fill-68" fill="#171717" points="79.0223249 61.6858467 81.6720523 61.6858467 81.6720523 59.669501 79.0223249 59.669501"></polygon>
                            <path d="M89.0714206,61.6854252 L89.0714206,59.6684775 C89.0641957,59.6684775 89.058175,59.6690796 89.0509501,59.6690796 L88.4759695,59.6690796 L88.4759695,61.6854252 L89.0714206,61.6854252 Z" id="Fill-69" fill="#171717"></path>
                            <path d="M89.0714206,61.6854252 L89.0714206,59.6684775 C89.0641957,59.6684775 89.058175,59.6690796 89.0509501,59.6690796 L88.4759695,59.6690796 L88.4759695,61.6854252 L89.0714206,61.6854252 Z" id="Fill-70" fill="#171717"></path>
                            <polygon id="Fill-71" fill="#171717" points="86.2080774 61.6858467 86.8035285 61.6858467 86.8035285 59.669501 86.2080774 59.669501"></polygon>
                            <polygon id="Fill-72" fill="#171717" points="86.2080774 61.6858467 86.8035285 61.6858467 86.8035285 59.669501 86.2080774 59.669501"></polygon>
                            <polygon id="Fill-73" fill="#171717" points="83.9406669 61.6858467 84.536118 61.6858467 84.536118 59.669501 83.9406669 59.669501"></polygon>
                            <polygon id="Fill-74" fill="#171717" points="83.9406669 61.6858467 84.536118 61.6858467 84.536118 59.669501 83.9406669 59.669501"></polygon>
                            <polygon id="Fill-75" fill="#171717" points="81.6720523 61.6858467 82.2675034 61.6858467 82.2675034 59.669501 81.6720523 59.669501"></polygon>
                            <polygon id="Fill-76" fill="#171717" points="81.6720523 61.6858467 82.2675034 61.6858467 82.2675034 59.669501 81.6720523 59.669501"></polygon>
                            <path d="M94.8211063,17.487659 L90.6926853,17.487659 C89.395818,17.487659 88.345199,18.538278 88.345199,19.8345432 L88.345199,20.0386463 L83.5268013,20.0386463 L84.8176478,22.9803796 L86.5106797,23.7191243 C87.0489338,23.3452364 87.6841218,23.1321022 88.345199,23.1321022 L88.345199,23.1989324 C88.345199,23.5794431 88.6534609,23.887705 89.0339716,23.887705 L94.8211063,23.887705 C96.2823398,23.887705 97.4672213,22.7034255 97.4672213,21.24159 L97.4672213,20.133774 C97.4672213,18.6719384 96.2823398,17.487659 94.8211063,17.487659" id="Fill-77" fill="#4EA19B">
                            <polygon id="Fill-81" fill="#CCE7E4" points="65.7803107 20.8893166 69.886455 20.8893166 69.886455 19.1884577 65.7803107 19.1884577"></polygon>                 
                            
                            <path d="M36.4743617,47.8513917 L60.9926187,47.8513917 L60.9926187,42.862607 L36.4743617,42.862607 L36.4743617,47.8513917 Z M35.2647952,48.0645259 C35.2647952,48.6148214 35.710932,49.0615603 36.2612275,49.0615603 L61.2057529,49.0615603 C61.7560485,49.0615603 62.2021853,48.6148214 62.2021853,48.0645259 L62.2021853,45.3569994 L62.2021853,43.3412558 L62.2021853,42.6488708 C62.2021853,42.0985752 61.7560485,41.6530405 61.2057529,41.6530405 L36.2612275,41.6530405 C35.710932,41.6530405 35.2647952,42.0985752 35.2647952,42.6488708 L35.2647952,43.3412558 L35.2647952,45.3569994 L35.2647952,48.0645259 Z" id="Fill-95" fill="#5ABCB5"></path>
                            <polygon id="Fill-96" fill="#CCE7E4" points="36.4743617 47.8513917 60.9926187 47.8513917 60.9926187 42.862607 36.4743617 42.862607"></polygon>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

And this is it's container:

```
 <div v-show="this.fileAdded == false" class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center pt-5 pb-6">
    // Here goes the SVG
</div>
```

This is the result:

[image]

[image]

I have tried every trick with padding, heigth and width, but none of this works.

Comment: The contents of the `<svg>` are irrelevant for the question being asked. What matters is the CSS applying to the actual `<svg>` element and to its parent, which you haven't provided. Please provide a *runnable* [mcve] which reproduces the issue and we'll be able to figure out what's wrong with your currently applying CSS (regardless of source - tailwind classes or any other source). Specifying a `height` (e.g: `.h-48` or bigger) on parent might fix it.

Comment: I would like to update this thred. The problem was a missplaced DIV,